# Weight Loss, help!

Tags: weight-loss, diet

I am 20 and have been going to the gym for a few months now, and haven't seen much result. I find it very hard to diet, as I have a limited variety of food that I can stomach and like, I have quite unpleasant IBS which is why I attend the gym. I need advice on how to loose weight and tone up quickly, without having to jump through to any 'diet hoops' please help?

Comment: You need to tell us a *whole lot more* if you want answers to be at all useful. See [this](http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/516/what-must-be-included-if-you-want-to-get-individualized-help) for what to include.

Answer (score 3):

Well this may or may not help. But I am a huge advocate of **Intermittent fasting**.

I have come to find that I also had IBS for years, not knowing the true cause of it or any way to fix it. I started intermittent fasting, and it gave my digestive system a break. I use a 16/8 Lean gains protocol. You can google it up. I have proceeded into my adventure by testing my body and discipline with not only 16 hour fasts, but 24 hour, and my longest went into today at 36 hours.

Now, I also spent several months in the gym at 185lbs with no weight loss, just muscular transformations. I also never liked to diet, but I started counting my calories, which led to counting my macro nutrients which led to me getting tired of eating all day long. So I watched the Hodgetwins and Low Carb Cory on youtube, and they were sharing information they previously researched and learned called Intermittent Fasting.

I started at 185lbs 23-25% Body fat. Overall stocky build, with a lot of bad fat around my midsection.

I am now 168lbs 13% Body fat. V Shape Back to waist look, nice traps and a strong core.

I can't chalk it all up to Intermittent fasting, but I followed a rigorous 4 day split workout schedule and intermittent fasted my last 3 months or so, from which I have received the best results of my life.

Here is some reference for you:

This is my eating schedule protocol

http://www.leangains.com/2010/04/leangains-guide.html

This was my initial training protocol

http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/get-swole-cory-gregory-muscle-building-trainer.html

This is what I do now, with lean gains in between.

http://stronglifts.com/eat-stop-eat-brad-pilon-fasting-review/

and I am on week 2 of this program

http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/shortcut-to-size.html

Keep in mind. People will call you stupid, people will think you're crazy, but people will also want what you have. They will want to look like you. Don't downplay it. Do your research. Work hard, Stay dedicated. When it's all done. Pass it along to a friend or family member who can also benefit from this lifestyle.

PEACE

Comment: I admit - fasting is good. You can loose ~10pounds in 5 days. Of course you do not have to fast for 5 days. One day a week is great. Moreover I find it easier not to eat at all than eat but less.

Comment: You're so right my dude, it's much easier to just NOT eat, than it is to tease yourself with mini-meals 6 times a day...but yes weight loss is extreme with intermittent fasting...

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the difference between different types of workout. The only fat burning workout is an aerobic workout. To loose weight you have to choose between few known aerobic workouts: long distance running, cycling, swimming, rowing and cross country skiing. The most of the workouts in the gym are anaerobic and help to build muscle mass and as side effect build fat in the body too. The aerobic exercises in the gym are extremely boring and ineffective.

Get some fresh air!